# PhpSpreadsheet display long number as text when generate xlxs

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I try to generate a long number as text using PhpSpreadsheet
but the number always display as scientific format,

i try to using

```
$sheet->setCellValueExplicit('G5', '8899900000083365', DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

it generate wrong number 8899900000083360, it change 5 to 0
same thing happend when i using

```
$sheet->getStyle("G5:G6"))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#');
```

and if i using

```
$sheet->getStyle("G5:G6"))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('@');
```

it back to scientific format

How can I generate the exact number of "8899900000083365"?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this and it worked

```
$sheet->setCellValueExplicit('G5', '8899900000083365', DataType::TYPE_STRING2);
```

Please note that it's `DataType::TYPE_STRING2` and not `DataType::TYPE_STRING`